# Grails 3 Code Coverage

Tags: grails, code-coverage

I am using Grails version 3.0.4 on Windows 7.  Does anyone know of a code coverage plugin or coverage tool that works for Grails 3?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

I use Cobertura. It works fine for me.

My `build.gradle` entries for Cobertura:

```
// in buildScript
maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
      }
```

```
// in dependencies block
classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.0"
```

```
// in plugins
id "net.saliman.cobertura" version "2.3.0"
```

and then

```
apply plugin: "net.saliman.cobertura".
```

Comment: I am using gradle 2.6

Answer (score 3):

Since Grails 3.0 has migrated to Gradle for its build you should be able to use code coverage plugins available there.  We have been using the [Cobertura Gradle Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.saliman.cobertura) with good success where I work.

Comment: Thank you.  I gave it a try and I think I can work with the Cobertura plugin.